# Making navbar stick to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <div class="header">
    <div class="navflex">
        <img src="logo.svg">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="box"><input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search"></li>
                <li><img src="notification.svg" class="notication"></li>
                <li><img src="user_1.svg"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
    ul{

    margin-left: 31px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

image{
    width: 100%;
}
.search-bar{
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar{
    /*background-color: #047aed;*/
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navflex{
    /*max-width: 1100px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: sticky;
     z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    
}

.navflex > nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    /*flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;*/
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: relative;*/

}
.navflex > nav {
    width: 100%;
}

.navflex > nav > ul > li {
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}

.navflex > nav > ul > li > input {
    width: 80%;
}

#box > input{
    width: 98%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px;
    background: url(search.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px;
    background-position: left;
}

#box{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to make my navbar sticky/fixed/absolute. I want it to be fixed at top of the page and when scroll it must not vanish away. I have tried changing the position attribute multiple times but have found no success. I also tried using z-index to be 100 and still there has been no change in navbar. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Look at CSS display: grid, which is pretty much designed for page layout issues like this

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work.

```css
ul{
    margin-left: 31px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

image{
    width: 100%;
}
.search-bar{
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar{
    /*background-color: #047aed;*/
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navflex{
    /*max-width: 1100px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: sticky;
     z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    
}

.navflex > nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    /*flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;*/
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: relative;*/

}
.navflex > nav {
    width: 100%;
}

.navflex > nav > ul > li {
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}

.navflex > nav > ul > li > input {
    width: 80%;
}

#box > input{
    width: 98%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px;
    background: url(search.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px;
    background-position: left;
}

#box{
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="navflex">
        <img src="logo.svg">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="box"><input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search"></li>
                <li><img src="notification.svg" class="notication"></li>
                <li><img src="user_1.svg"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The navbar is fixed. But when I scroll down, the search bar also wraps over other elements.

Comment: @Beginner, my answer is similar to Stavreski01's answer. If his worked properly, my answer should work too.

Comment: Even that didnt worked.I mean same error in that too

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The navbar is fixed. But when I scroll down, the search bar also wraps over other elements